# Android add a watermark logo to very large jpg file (say 10000 x 150000)

Tags: java, android, bitmap, jpeg

I have a large jpeg file say 10000 x 150000 px. I want to add a small logo to the bottom of the image without re sizing.

I am able to do this If i down sample the original image and draw the logo using canvas.But when i finally save it to file, the image original size will be reduced as I am sampling it.

If i load the original image into bitmap without down sampling, it exceeds the VM.

Answer (score 1):

Below code work for me :-

```
public static Bitmap mark(Bitmap src, String watermark, Point location, Color color, int alpha, int size, boolean underline) {
    int w = src.getWidth();
    int h = src.getHeight();
    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, src.getConfig());

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
    canvas.drawBitmap(src, 0, 0, null);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(color);
    paint.setAlpha(alpha);
    paint.setTextSize(size);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setUnderlineText(underline);
    canvas.drawText(watermark, location.x, location.y, paint);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Exactly this is what I am doing right now. But if you see we need a source image loaded into bitmap. This is where the app is getting crashed. Anyway this works if we down sample the image. But in the final output Image should be of same resolution.

Comment: This answer might not the perfect solution. As the asker said, the bitmap resolution is 3888x2592, it will take up about 38MB memory if you decode to memory directly without any sampling or processing.

Comment: @SaiMukesh i donot think so android allow you to show image on app bcz all app have limited size or heap as well as . You never knows how much size in heap. As per my knowledge without scaling work always giving you crash ...

Comment: @alijandro you are right I am just giving him a way how to achieve his  task. for your info I am not talking about 38 mb pic load in bitmap.

Comment: @Duggu : May be android may not give this. But this image then will be uploaded to server where it will be viewed on a machine which is capable of displaying it.

Comment: this mobile app and image size not more than 5 MB as per my knowledge so you must have to decrease your images size other wise it will crash any time when load pic into your app...

Answer (score 1):

For large image editing you'll need to use native tools like [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/index.php). Because there seem to be a lack of advanced image processing libraries in android supported Java.

If you can compile [Composite](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/composite.php) tool's binaries for android. Then you can use them with [`--limit`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#limit) option to work with limited memory.

Also, you can try [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html) as an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BitmapRegionDecoder` when deal with large image file. From the [official document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapRegionDecoder.html).

> BitmapRegionDecoder can be used to decode a rectangle region from an image. BitmapRegionDecoder is particularly useful when an original image is large and you only need parts of the image.
>   To create a BitmapRegionDecoder, call newInstance(...). Given a BitmapRegionDecoder, users can call decodeRegion() repeatedly to get a decoded Bitmap of the specified region.

Just decode the part of your image that you need to add watermark, then use `Canva` to draw text on it.

```
try {
    BitmapRegionDecoder regionDecoder = BitmapRegionDecoder.newInstance("/sdcard/test.png", true);
    Bitmap bitmap = regionDecoder.decodeRegion(rect, options);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Ok.. But how do i save the edited small portion of image back to original file??